# Get Title Block data from DWG(AutoCad) Files using C#

Tags: c#, autocad, cad

I want to write a console app that will read the Title Block Data from DWG Cad File. How do I do it all the instructions that I find is about CAD Plugins. Please assist.

Comment: By this point you may already have an answer, but just in case, you cannot write it to read the drawing data directly from a separate executable unless you want to purchase the Real DWG SDK.  Otherwise, it has to be a plug-in.  However, that doesn't mean you can't create a separate executable.  I do this all the time.  I have a class library that is always loaded in AutoCAD and an Exe and the two can communicate either via file transfer of data or via WCF communications.  You can also use COM to communicate with SendCommand().  I think you can also create a COM Interface.

Comment: Thanks yeah i wrote a plugin to extract information.